# Can't return elements from two-dimensional array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a feature that saves a title and link to a website

This is what I am attempting to store

```
[0] -> [TITLE, LINK]
[1] -> [TITLE, LINK]
[2] -> [TITLE, LINK]
```

This is how I am doing it

```
//Create array
var favoriteProducts = [[String:String]]()
                            
//Add products
let firstArray = [titleName:String(), link:String()]

favoriteProducts.append(firstArray)
                            
//Add to defaults
UserDefaults.standard.set(favoriteProducts, forKey: "favProducts")
```

The next step is to loop through using `ForEach` to return the title and link. For debugging I'm trying to use

```
UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favProducts")![0][0]
```

Which returns

```
Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts
```

However

```
UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favProducts")![0]
```

Returns

```
(website, link)
```

So my question here is how do I return both the website and link individually and not just the entire subscript?

Comment: You may want to learn the difference between [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) and [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary). For short hand `[]` is an `Array` while `[ : ]` is an `Dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store arrayOfStrings In struct array and can access the vale from struct ,Say example

```
    var favouriteProducts = [[String:Any]]()
    var listOfSite = [SiteDetail]()
    
    var firstArray = ["titleName":"String","link":"firstlink"]
    var secondArray = ["titleName":"s","link":"s"]
    
    favouriteProducts.append(firstArray)
    favouriteProducts.append(secondArray)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(favouriteProducts, forKey: "favProducts")
    
    let value = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favProducts") as? [[String:String]] ?? [[:]]
    
    for values in value{
        let siteName = values["titleName"] as? String ?? ""
        let link = values["link"] as? String ?? ""
        let siteDetail = SiteDetail(website: siteName, link: link)
        listOfSite.append(siteDetail)
    }
    
    print("listOf \(listOfSite[0].link)")
    print("listOf \(listOfSite[0].website)")

 //////////////////////////

  struct SiteDetail{
    var website:String?
    var link:String?
  }
```

Comment: @user302975,Will above Helps

Answer (score 0):

Here `UserDefaults.standard.array` returns an array of `Any` type and you are storing an array of the dictionary. So at the time of retrieve, you need to cast the array element as a dictionary.

Also, you can use the key to get the dictionary value.

```
let firstElement = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favProducts")?[0] as? [String: String])
let title = firstElement?["titleName"]
let link = firstElement?["link"]
```

Comment: var favoriteProducts = [[String:String]]() is not a two dimensional array. it's just an array of dictionaries. You are getting the above error because of that only

Comment: @GavidiHarikrishna thanks for pointing it out. Yes, the title and post do not match here.

Comment: Using the above method returns `nil`

Comment: @user302975 can you please correct your post first?  Read the post comment and answere comment.

Comment: I've updated it with what I am trying to achieve @RajaKishan

Comment: for```[TITLE, LINK]```  is not a proper type ```[[String:String]]()```. It's a ```[[String]]()```

Comment: I would use `first` instead of `[0]`. The outer parentheses is not needed